# Security vulnerabilities to JMX Exporter in Prometheus

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, prometheus, jmx-exporter, prometheus-java

I want to expose kafka and zookeeper metrics in prometheus. I do not want to use jmx_exporter because to integrate this I need to expose a port which has security vulnerabilities. Prometheus also has a third-party kafka_exporter. Is it possible to use Kafka_exporter without exposing jmx port? 
Or is there any other way I can get Kafka and zookeeper metrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there are multiple "kafka exporters" for prometheus

[This one](https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter) is written in Golang, and does not require JMX.

You could also set `com.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true` to protect the JMX ports to clients with valid keys